# How to find a matrix from eigenvectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

For this problem, normally I am given two eigenvalues each with a corresponding eigenvector. However, I am having trouble when given an eigenvector containing two vectors… How do I approach this?

Eigenvalue #1 = 2 with {[1,3,1]}

Eigenvalue #2 = 1 with {[2,1,-1], [0,2,1]}

How do I find the matrix?  The second eigenvalue confuses me.

Answer (score 2):

Let 
$$D=\operatorname{diag}(2,1,1)$$
and the matrix
$$P=\left(\begin{matrix}1&2&0\\
3&1&2\\
1&-1&1\end{matrix}\right)$$
then the desired matrix is
$$A=PDP^{-1}$$

Comment: I thought that the eigenvectors need to be mutually orthogonal?

Comment: No it suffices that the eigenvectors form a basis.